# Constraint to array dimension in C language

Tags: c

```
int KMP( const char *original, int o_len, const char *substring, int s_len ){
if( o_len < s_len )
    return -1;

int k = 0;
int cur = 1;

int fail[ s_len ];

fail[ k ] = -1;

while( cur < s_len ){
    k = cur - 1;
    do{
        if( substring[ cur ] == substring[ k ] ){
            fail[ cur ] = k;

            break;
        }else{
            k = fail[ k ] + 1;
        }
    }while( k );    

    if( !k && ( substring[ cur ] != substring[ 0 ] ) ){
        fail[ cur ] = -1;
    }else if( !k ){
        fail[ cur ] = 0;
    }

    cur++;
}

k = 0;
cur = 0;

while( ( k < s_len ) && ( cur < o_len ) ){
    if( original[ cur ] == substring[ k ] ){
        cur++;
        k++;
    }else{
        if( k == 0 ){
            cur++;
        }else{
            k = fail[ k - 1 ] + 1;
        }
    }
}

if( k == s_len )
    return cur - k;
else
    return -1;
}
```

This is a KMP algorithm I once coded. When I reviewed it this morning, I find it strange that an integer array is defined as int fail[ s_len ]. Does the specification requires dimesion of arrays compile-time constant? How can this code pass the compilation?
By the way, my gcc version is 4.4.1.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ability to define arrays using a variable as the dimension was added to C in C99. It's also supported as an extension by some C++ compilers, but isn't part of the C++ Standard, and won't be part of C++0x. If you are planning on portability to C89 compilers, or to C++, it's best not to use it.

Answer (score 2):

To complement Neil's answer: this feature is called VLA - [Variable Length Array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). It was indeed added in C99 and is currently supported by several compilers. Its usage is discouraged for [other reasons](http://www.clarkcox.com/blog/2009/04/07/c99s-vlas-are-evil/) as well, in addition to the portability problem Neil mentioned